# how did this forked in the rest api route go wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Update: This problem was solved. I followed the advice of the replies and tried the console.log(req.body) command. Turns out it was calling a different function. Now at the time I was using postman to test the API and I learned that editing an already saved function is not the same as with other text or media editors and you have to make a completely new function to test it. I.E. I used a previous post function to create user and changed some elements, turns out postman doesnt like that and just ran the old function.

Thanks for the help everyone

I made an admin route using an already working user route exactly except using fewer values.

I keep getting an undefined error during validation when ever I try to run a post function. what could have gone wrong here? Or where should I look for the error, I checked the spellings of each of the values Iam using in the create admin function but I see no spelling problems?

Error in Console:

```
Error: admin validation failed: AdminEMail: Path `AdminEMail` is required., AdminPassword: Path `AdminPassword` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:48:26)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:563:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:221:10)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1693:40)
    at Object.Console.<computed> (internal/console/constructor.js:272:10)
    at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:282:61)
    at D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\routes\Admin.js:25:21
    at D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4876:16
    at D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
    at D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4899:21
    at D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:493:16
    at D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:246:48
    at next (D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:167:27)
    at next (D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:169:9)
    at Kareem.execPost (D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:217:3)
    at _handleWrapError (D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\kareem\index.js:245:21) {
  errors: {
    AdminEMail: ValidatorError: Path `AdminEMail` is required.
        at validate (D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1178:13)
        at D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1161:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1106:14)
        at D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2379:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:76:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'AdminEMail',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    },
    AdminPassword: ValidatorError: Path `AdminPassword` is required.
        at validate (D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1178:13)
        at D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1161:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1106:14)
        at D:\Downloads\Compressed\api-master_3\api-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2379:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:76:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'AdminPassword',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'admin validation failed'
}
```

And Here is the route:

```
//Imported modules
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Imported models
const Admin = require('../models/admin');
//const User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.send("We are on Admin");
  })

//Admin Functions

//Creation of new Admin
router.post("/signup", (req,res) => {
    const admin = new Admin({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        AdminEMail: req.body.AdminEMail,
        AdminPassword: req.body.AdminPassword
    });
    admin.save(function(err,admin){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
            return
        }
        console.log("New admin created");
        res.send(admin);
    })
})

//Admin Login and verification
router.post("/login", (req,res) => {
    const AdminID = req.body.AdminID;
    const Username = req.body.username;
    const Password = req.body.password;

    Admin.findOne({_id:AdminID}, function(err, foundAdmin){
        if(err){
          res.send("<h1>got clicked</h1>");
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          if(foundAdmin){
            if(foundAdmin.AdminEMail === Username){
                if(foundAdmin.AdminPassword === Password){
                    res.send("logged in");
                }
                else{
                    res.send("Username and Password Mismatch");
                }
            }
            else{
                res.send("Username and ID Mismatch");
            }
          }
          else{
              res.send("No Such admin exists");
          }
        }

      });

});

//
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Try doing `console.log(req.body)` and see what it outputs. It seems like the properties you're looking for aren't being included as you're expecting (the error implies that `req.body.AdminEMail` and `req.body.AdminPassword` are `undefined`)

Comment: which one? I see three routes. Also, the error sounds pretty clear: you didn't send the required data (so probably fix your HTML form for that) _and_ you're not checking to see whether `req.body` has what you need before running code that uses those values.

Comment: Maybe you are missing `body-parser` .